# Capybara / Rails /Ember unable to fill_in login and password fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, capybara

- Able to bring up the page when running with the following steps Cucumber:

  ```
  Given(/^i go to the login page$/) do
  visit "http://localhost:3000"
  end

  When(/^i enter a valid email and password$/) do
  fill_in('email', :with => 'customer@test.com')
  ```
- However i keep getting the following error:

  ```
   When i enter a valid email and password # 
  features/step_definitions/loggingin_valid.rb:5
  Unable to find field "email" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/loggingin_valid.rb:6:in `/^i enter a valid email and
  password$/'
  features/loggingin_valid.feature:5:in `When i enter a valid email and password'**
  ```

Ember js:

```
6        form.form-inline submit="login"
7         h2 Log In
8          Ember.TextField valueBinding="email"
9          Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="password" 
11         input type="submit" value="Log In"  
13          linkTo "register" |Register Now
```

Webpage:

```
<form class="form-inline" data-ember-action="1">
<h2>Log In</h2>
<input id="ember440" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text">
<input id="ember441" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="password">
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
<a id="ember444" class="ember-view" href="#/register">Register Now</a>
</form>
```

Just cant work out how i input text into the email and password fields. They are dynamic so i cant use the ID. Thought there maybe a way to use the "type" but havent been successful with that either. any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ids to your elements.  Ember will only generate them automatically if you don't.

```
Ember.TextField valueBinding="email" id="email"
Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="password" id="password"
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, Thought there may have been a way to find the 'type' fields and just fill_in the text.seems fairly logical doing it as you suggested. Will give that a shot.